# resend response after request.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am experiencing difficulty in writing the correct callback.
When a user makes a request to "/city" server must make a request to a third-party service to query the data. For this I do http.request(), to request and receive data (there is no problem). And then I need to transfer the data to the res.send() outside getCity() function.

I have no idea. Please, explain me the solution and working principle.  Thank you!

```
var getCity = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
      //what to do?
  });
}

app.get('/city', function (req, res) {
    var request = http.request(options, getCity);
    request.end();  
    res.send("ok"); //need sending str from getCity instead of "ok";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend using following approach to do some resolving kind of tasks,

```
var cityDecorator = function(req,res,next) {
  var str = ''
  http.request(options, function(response){
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () { 
        req.params.cityValue = str; // N1
        next(); // N2
    });
  }).end();
}

app.get('/city',cityDecorator, function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.cityValue);
});
```

N1 : You can send response from that line only, but i prefer and recommend that send response from one file only, so in future if you want to change res, or want to decorate, or render or whatever, you just have to deal with one file, ie your routes file.

This will work only if you are using express, from your code looks like you do, but if not then comment, i will provide solution for that scenario.
GL

Comment: Wow, it works!
But I do not understand how "next()" works... app.get() looks like app.get('/city', callback(req, res, next) [,callback(req, res, next)...]) when "next" call new callback?

Comment: Its called Router level middleware, so it will jump to next callback function or if no callback functions define, then matching route will trigger. Read more here : http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router